# REST Get for multi values with multi keys

Tags: rest

I have a RESTful server that implement get request for an entity while the entity have multi keys. For example, getting contact information for a specific company in a specific country (Nike, Germany):

```
GET: http://hostname/rest/accounts/{company}/{country}
```

I want to add a functionality it to allow the client to query multiple company/countries pairs in one call. Since I have millions of records in the DB I don't ever want to return all the data. Also, the client may need ~1000 records, so I don't want him to make ~1000 calls.

I thought of adding the pairs of company/country in the body of the request, but the answer here [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) suggested it's a bad practice.

I can't use the query string params because I have to much information and most servers have a limit on the size of the URL.

What's a good REST practice for such a case?

Answer (score 1):

There is an official proposal for a multi-request protocol - [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-httpbis-mget-00) ([background](http://www.chmod777self.com/2013/03/a-proposal-multiple-request-uris-in.html)). Possibly because it relies on HTTP/2 to deliver the efficiency gain, it doesn't seem to have much momentum at present.

For a few resources, you could specify them all in the URL. The problem is the de-facto URL limit of [~2000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers). While it applies primarily to IE, I think a good API should work well in browsers, and it probably applies elsewhere because of IE's restriction.

For that reason, I think you have two choices.

Realistically you will need to use a POST request where the body contains a list of requested paths, e.g. as a JSON-encoded array. It's generally bad practice as the reference suggests, but it's generally considered reasonable in this situation. The practical downside is it's not cacheable.